# How do I add a rails controller variable to javascript file console.log?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, erb

I have added a variable to a rails controller.

```
@fart = "I farted"
```

I added a file to the assets/javascripts folder called fart.js.erb (for preprocessing)

The file contains one line

```
console.log("<%=@fart%>");
```

My expected result would be that it prints "I farted" to the console. Instead, it prints a blank line.

I have tried different variations of

```
console.log("<%='@fart'%>");
console.log("<%=@fart.html_safe%>");
console.log("<%=@fart%>");
```

none of which work. How do I print my fart correctly?

Comment: Inspect the generated fart.js to see what's in the file.

Answer (score 1):

See if this smells better:

```
console.log('<%=@fart%>');
```

You don't need the double-quotes for interpolation to work in a .erb file.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
console.log("<%=@fart.to_json%>");
```